# Chinese or Japanese characters in Apex getting converted to ??????

Tags: salesforce, apex

When I read the field from the salesforce object, the query result is coming as ???? but in database it is stored correctly. Not sure what is the issue.

Suppose Contact.LocaleName__c  = '会社 エフ';

Contact ct =[SELECT Id, LocaleName__c FROM Contact  WHERE id=:contactId];
system.debug('test-'+ct.LocaleName__c);

This printed correctly = test- 会社 エフ

but when I used inside a class it converted to "test-??????"